# Is there a portable C compiler for windows?

Tags: c, windows, compiler-construction, portability

I want to carry one in my flash drive and run it.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) is a pretty good one and can be easily copied to a flash drive.  Admittedly this is a port of GCC, but it works well in Windows.  A drawback of this compiler is that it does not understand some of the specific Microsoft [keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bh0054z.aspx) that can be used when compiling with `cl.exe`.

Answer (score 17):

[TCC (Tiny C Compiler)](http://bellard.org/tcc/) fits on a floppy and does not require installation.

Comment: It's no longer in development.

Comment: Still seems to work very well on < 2013 Windows systems for anyone wondering.

Answer (score 5):

[Digital Mars C and C++ compiler](http://www.digitalmars.com/)

Comment: also has a **[cl shell](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/cl.html)** for easy Microsoft interchangeability.

Answer (score 3):

You can Try if u want **Pocket C++**(its portable) the interface is from **Notepad++** and is very easy and friendly for use: https://github.com/dacap/pocketcpp

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the [Portable C Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_C_Compiler)

Windows download: [here](http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se/ftp/pub/win32/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DevCpp

https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

It supports C, and C++

Comment: DevCpp isn't updated since 3 years and I think it uses a very old version of gcc. I'd take a newer version of gcc directly.