# Why does my external compiler throw error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, process, g++

I am making a game about programming and I want to add code editor with g++ compiler which player can use.

My variables:

```
    private readonly string directoryPath = $"{Application.persistentDataPath}/tmp";
    private readonly string outputFilePath = $"{Application.persistentDataPath}/tmp/pablo.exe";
    private readonly string inputFilePath = $"{Application.persistentDataPath}/tmp/usercode.cpp";
    private readonly string compilerPath = $"\"{Application.streamingAssetsPath}/g++.exe\" ";
```

Code responsible for compiling:

```
private void Compile()
{
    CreateFile(); // Function that creates file with code
    //UnityEngine.Debug.Log(compilerPath + "-o \"" + outputFilePath + "\" " + "\"" + inputFilePath + "\"");
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = compilerPath,
            Arguments = "-o \"" + outputFilePath + "\" " + "\"" + inputFilePath + "\"",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    process.WaitForExit();

    if (process.ExitCode == 0)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Compilation succeeded");
    }
    else
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Compilation failed: " + error);
    }
}
```

And I have compiler(g++) directly in root of my StreamingAssets folder, but when I try to run my code, it occures an error:
StreamingAssets structure:

```
StreamingAssets/
├─ g++.exe
```

> Compilation failed: g++.exe: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus':
> CreateProcess: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

The command compiler is executing: `"D:/.Coding/games/newHero/New Hero/Assets/StreamingAssets/g++.exe" -o "C:/Users/Viroz/AppData/LocalLow/TCG/New Hero/tmp/pablo.exe" "C:/Users/Viroz/AppData/LocalLow/TCG/New Hero/tmp/usercode.cpp"`

When I try it in terminal it also gives me the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that g++ just gets things rolling. There are a buttload of other tools used by g++ to do the heavy lifting. You can't just carry around g++.exe, you need the whole toolchain.

Comment: @user4581301 so what should I add to make it work?

Comment: Path of least resistance? When installing your program, test for a pre-existing compiler that matches your requirements. If you don't find one, install GCC. But do it carefully so that you don't cause any collisions with other GCC installs the user may already have.

Comment: Can I use any pre-built solution? Is there a way for me to put the files into unity StreamingAssets.

Comment: GCC is pretty portable, so yes, but you'll need someone more familiar than me with the packaging tool you're using to tell you how to do it. You should re-work this question and direct it at experts of that packaging system.

Comment: Could try some of those https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643580/is-there-a-portable-c-compiler-for-windows